# Summing only the available columns in a data frame

Tags: r, sum

I have the following two data frames:

```
a<-1,2,3,4,5
b<-3,4,5,6,7
d<-"a","b","c","d","e"
df1<-data.frame(a,b,d)

a<-1,2,3,4,5
c<-3,4,5,6,7
e<-"a","b","c","d","e"
df2<-data.frame(a,c,e)
```

I want to get in both data frames a column called total which sums a+b+c. Since column c is missing in df1, and column b is missing in df2, I get the error "replacement has 0 rows, data has 5123" (uninitialized column)

But is there a way in which you can sum these columns by just skipping the missing columns?
This means that I want to get the following:

```
df1$total<-sum(df1$a+df1$b)
df2$total<-sum(df2$a+df2$c)
```

Comment: `rowSums(df1[sapply(df1, is.numeric)])`?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because you significantly changed the meaning of your question after an answer was given. If you have a follow-up issue please ask a new question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/6574038

Comment: Thanks for your help, and you are totally right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a slightly more general context (there are numeric columns in the data.frame that you don't want to include in the sum) you could do something like the following:

```
col2sum <- c("a", "b", "c")
df1$total <- rowSums(Filter(is.numeric, df1[names(df1) %in% col2sum]))
df1
  a b c f total
1 1 3 a 2     4
2 2 4 b 3     6
3 3 5 c 4     8
4 4 6 d 5    10
5 5 7 e 6    12
df2$total <- rowSums(Filter(is.numeric, df2[names(df2) %in% col2sum]))
df2
  a c d e total
1 1 4 a 1     5
2 2 5 b 2     7
3 3 6 c 3     9
4 4 7 d 4    11
5 5 8 e 5    13
```

Alternatively:

```
rowSums(df2[names(df2) %in% col2sum & sapply(df2, is.numeric)])
```

** Data **

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 3:7, c = letters[1:5], f = 2:6)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, c = 4:8, d = letters[1:5], e = 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Select with `sapply()`, then `rowSums()`

```
df1$total <- rowSums(df1[, sapply(df1, is.numeric)])
```

***Yielding***

```
> df1
  a b c total
1 1 3 a     4
2 2 4 b     6
3 3 5 c     8
4 4 6 d    10
5 5 7 e    12
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=3:7, c=letters[1:5])
```

Comment: This sums f too, which is unwanted, isn't?

Comment: @snoram There was no `f` before, OP has [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51176085/revisions) question after my answer.

Comment: @snoram Hope you don't mind I have rolled back OP's edits, please see my comment to the question.

Comment: Sure. no problem.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I forgot to add a comment after changing the OP or ask a new question. Anyway, although your answer answer answers the original question and will get an upvote, I am accepting the answer by snoram since that was the answer I am looking for